# How to call a variable value from .tpl file into another .tpl file?

Tags: php, opencart

I am designing invoice for OPENCART WEBSITE. I need to use a variable value i.e. $consignment['pname'] from order_info.tpl file and use it into order_invoice.tpl. The value $consignment['pname'] contains Courier Partner name. I tried -

```
<?php ini_set('include_path','\template\saccount\order_info.tpl');

    echo $consignment['pname'];
```

?>

But it didn't worked. Any help appreciated.
Smarty is not used but it uses model view control design.

Comment: Did you try including the file before using the variable?

Comment: Are you using `smarty`? Or any other template engine?

Comment: Smarty is not used. Uses model view control design.

Comment: Any idea appreciated

Comment: Pass the variable in the controller that renders `order_invoice.tpl`